# Angular 2+ application deployed on S3 gives routing issue

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

We are hosting a static Angular 2 website on Amazon S3.

Our app is deployed at http://abc.domain.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html
If the user is not logged in, our app redirects the user to the login page: http://abc.domain.s3.amazonaws.com/Platform/Login which works fine.

However, if you refresh http://abc.domain.s3.amazonaws.com/Platform/Login (or access it directly), it returned the "NoSuchKey, The specified key does not exist" error.

We have set "Index Document" and "Error Document" to index.html. And the bucket has public access. But we are unable to resolve this issue.

We are not using cloudfront with S3 and route53.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you set bucket policy and cors configuration ?

Comment: Check answer have u set bucket policy as per below

Comment: thanks @aviboy2006 for the answer, I will check it

Comment: is this worked for you ? still facing issue ?

Comment: Thanks!! It works, one question
- my site is https://abc.domain.s3.amazonaws.com/Platform/Login
its giving https ( not secure ) warrning.
- Also i want this S3 url to my custom domain link ( abc.domain.com )

Comment: create route53 entry and select S3 bucket. If you want to use https then you have to first get certificate from AWS certificate mangeer for that domain and create cloudfront.  you can ask separate question and give your will answer in details

Comment: Check this as you  new user. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i had created one separate question for custom url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your bucket policy setting. If not set then use below to set bucket policy under **Permission -> Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt126637111000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.xyz.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3 Access Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::142412414124:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::www.xyz.com/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::www.xyz.com"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also check for CORS Configuration.You can find under 
**Permission -> CORS Configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today but fixed this by going into Static Website Hosting on the S3 Service and adding the Error Document URL which was listed as optional. However setting this to index.html resolved the error.